# How to get Collection object throug Many to Many relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

Friends I've following models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :milestones_projects
  has_many :milestones, :through => :milestones_projects
  validates :projectname, :presence=>true, :length=> {:maximum=>250}, :uniqueness=>true
  validates :location,:presence=>true
end

class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :milestones_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :milestones_projects

  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 250}
  validates :days, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 3}
  validates :stage, :presence => true
end


class MilestonesProjects < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :milestones,:foreign_key => 'milestone_id'
  belongs_to :projects,:foreign_key => 'project_id'
end
```

So i have many-to-many relationship between project and milestone.

in irb, I want to get collection object, so I'm using as following

```
irb(main):001:0> me=Project.find(1)
=> #<Project id: 1, location_id: 1, projectname: "Sample 2", description: "Sample 2", i
spublished: true, created_at: "2011-09-02 08:26:41", updated_at: "2011-09-07 10:26:48">
```

here 'me' is an array contains first project details, and now i"m trying to get milestone details associated with this project. for this I'm trying as follows

```
irb(main):002:0> me.milestones
```

but it's giving me error like

NameError: uninitialized constant Project::MilestonesProject
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/base.rb:1205:in `compute_type'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:162:in`send'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `klass'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:346:in`source_reflection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:346:in `collect'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:346:in`source_reflection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/reflection.rb:377:in `check_validity!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:61:in`initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:23:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:11:in`initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/associations.rb:1483:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/
active_record/associations.rb:1483:in`milestones'
        from (irb):2
        from :0

so friends please help me..

i need to execute some commands like

```
milestone_count=project.milestones.size
```

Comment: Could you add the schema of your rails project (the part with milestones, projects, and milestone_projects). And could you edit your post so that the stack trace is indented 4 spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your quick response! 
Finally i found the solution, both the answers posted here are correct..

i changed my models like this

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_milestones
  has_many :milestones, :through => :project_milestones
end

class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :project_milestones
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_milestones
end

class ProjectMilestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :milestone,:foreign_key => 'milestone_id'
  belongs_to :project,:foreign_key => 'project_id'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the naming conventions of rails are here the problem. Rails thinks that your model objects are singular, and your data base tables are plural. Rails could have a problem with a model named `MilestonesProjects`, it should be named `MilestoneProject` because that is it: the relation between one `Milestone` and one `Project`. Have a look at the example in ["Guide to Active Records"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), section 2.4 and where singular and plural is used.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your MilestonesProjects model

```
class MilestonesProjects < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :milestone,:foreign_key => 'milestone_id'
  belongs_to :project,:foreign_key => 'project_id'
end
```